# how to make gaps of light between objects?

Tags: objects, lighting

[image]

It is necessary to make gaps of light without separating the objects of the clouds from each other

Comment: Use AO as factor for Mix Shader ... ?

Comment: If you don't know what AO is that @vklidu mentioned, the node is called _Ambient Occlusion_. I just mention it because not all newbies might know the abbreviation and if you enter AO in the search bar, you'll get _AOV Output_ as first result (at least in my Blender).

Comment: I would say there's a light inside with subsurface scattering applied.

Comment: Thanks @GordonBrinkmann :) ... weekend run. Since JagJB's answer I'm not sure if image is reference or issue of current state ...

Comment: @vklidu Yes, I understand what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly, here is a proposal with shaders:

[image]

Comment: I think it's going to rain soon ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One way can be **Ambient Occlusion** as *Factor* of *Mix Shader* node ... just inverted by *Colour Ramp* node (or by *Map Range* node).

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks, it worked. I would never have thought to use AO

Comment: Great if worked for you ... Consider mark as accepted https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour